# Fresh install of IIS, HTTP Error 401.3 - Unauthorized?

Tags: iis, iis-7.5

I just installed IIS on my Windows 7 box and am having some authentication problems.

The error I get when I try to direct my browser to 127.0.0.1 is:

> Server Error in Application "DEFAULT WEB SITE" HTTP Error 401.3 -
>   Unauthorized You do not have permission to view this directory or page
>   because of the access control list (ACL) configuration or encryption
>   settings for this resource on the Web server.

How do I fix this? Do I need to change some settings in the inetmgr tool?